# PostMapping errors asking for GetMapping

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, http-post

I am trying to save data to my Postgres database.  This should use a PostMapping annotation on the method so that it sends the object accordingly.  However, for some reason it is expecting a "GET" method.  Any thoughts and if others have run into a similar issue.  I also cannot debug into that method as well.

**Inventory.java**

```
@RestController
public class InventoryController {
    @Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Inventory addItem(@RequestBody(required = false) Inventory item) {
        System.out.print("This is a test");
        return inventoryService.save(item);
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testMethod() {
        return "Method works!";
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>   Request method 'GET' not supported
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'GET' not supported    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:201)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:421)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:449)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:393)

I have tried the following annotations on the "addItem" method and it still returns the aforementioned trace.

1. @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
2. @PostMapping(path="/add")

I am running Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: Are you sure that frontend is calling the POST method instead of GET ?  I suspect that

Comment: can you post, what API you are calling or curl request?

Comment: Oh my goodness.  I need to head to bed.  I was hitting the end point using my browser.  There was nothing wrong with the code but rather with the application used.  I downloaded Postman and performed the request and the end point was hit without the "GET" request method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not **asking for GetMapping**, the error said **Request method 'GET' not supported**. It means you call endpoint for HttpGet Method, but your defined endpoint in the Controller is HttpPost Method !

Call using curl, should be like below :

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/add
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add @ResponseBody as in @RestController is combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody. Also try to test the code from PostMan alike tools before handing over API end points to Frontend or mobile team.

Example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {
...
...

@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}

}
```

Also sometime if we get any particular resource by Id so we should check if resource is null than return blank object or standard NOT_FOUND error, error we can override with @RestControllerAdvice extended from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler where we can extended all the error on controller level.

But if error comes in resource server, so in that case we have to add entrypoints in websecurity configure -> http security method overrid and add custom entrypoint as well failure and success handlers.

Comment: I think this is not the answer but a coding suggestion.